# Resize Ubuntu Left Panel Height

Tags: 16.04, unity

Is there a way to resize Ubuntu's left panel height just like the one that Kali Linux has?

[image]

Comment: What version of ubuntu do you have ? Kali uses gnome shell 3.xx. You could try Ubuntu Gnome if you want that.

Comment: Which Ubuntu flavour (or better, which desktop environment) do you use? The plain vanilla Ubuntu uses Unity Desktop. Are you okay with switching to a  different desktop environment? As solsTiCe already mentioned, Kali Linux uses some kind of Gnome desktop.